# how to create widget in Yii based on existing login action view?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

how to create a widget out of an existing login action view ?
this is what I currently have in my login.php view file of the site's controller actinLogin()

```
<div id="login-wrapper">
<div class="login-container">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'login-form','enableAjaxValidation'=>true,)); ?>
            <div class="login-input">
            <p>
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'username')); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'password')); ?>
            </p>
            <div id="bmenu">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="register"><?php echo CHtml::link("Registration", array('wsmembers/register'));?></li>
                    <li class="login"><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login',array('id'=>'login_button')); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- .login-container -->
<div class="login-bg-bottom"></div>
```

if I click the default login link from the navbar, that's the only time that code above shows
the login box at the upper right corner of the page

but the problem is, the login box should be at the homepage and must already be there
without clicking a login link at the navbar. so how am i gonna do that? this have something to do with main.php layout file right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.

What you have defined is a view that is used for content. If you click the link the login action will be executed and it it will show the form.

If you want this to be shown always, just do a Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial on the view. Note that it cannot be $this->renderPartial as you would normally do since the main layout is not executed by the controller. I usually define an alias called "userViews" that points to protected/views so I can do:

```
Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('userViews.site.login');
```

Or something like that. Hope that helps :)

As for the alias you can add this to your config:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('userViews', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../protected/views');
```

This is assuming your views are indeed under protected views.

Comment: in what part of the main config should I place that setPathOfAlias ?, is it inside the components array? OR outside the components array?, and also the main config returns an array,so how will I insert that in the array itself? what's the key for that ?

Comment: I define those before the return array() starts. You can place them pretty much anywhere in your code (the parts that are executed) but I like to keep those in the config-file.

Comment: but how ?  you mean to say, I can just add it there without a key? like e.g return array( Yii::setPathOfAlias('userViews', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../protected/views'), 'key'=>'value','key'=>'value'    ?

Comment: Like I said: before it :) Yii::setPathOfAlias(); return array(); It's not because the file is supposed to return an array that you can't do anything else in there :)

Comment: ok, i got this Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object , maybe because my code pasted above is passing a model,so when I renderpartial it at the main.php layout, it's throwing this error, any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: You obviously need the model so why not just create an instance of it in your main.php and pass that along as a parameter?

Comment: I used a widget instead in order to solve the problem but thanks for your tips and suggestions, I might use that someday :)